# onchange is not triggering while typing in input type inside ngFor in anguar4

Tags: angular, onchange, ngfor

Here is my code:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of Object.keys(settings.columns)">
  <input type="text" value="{{item}}" (change)="changed($event.target.value, item)">
</div>
```

Here the changed event is triggering `onblur` (if I click on some other place after entering data).

But not while I type. How do I get notified while typing?

Comment: The standard way for Angular would be: `<input type="text" [ngModel]="item" (ngModelChange)="changed($event, item)" />`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typing is not yet a change. Try listening for keyup:

```
<input (keyup)="changed($event)">
```

Comment: or for input: `<input (input)="changed($event)">`